# Is my comment valid / did I do the right thing?

Tags: support, comments

[Why do we have same chord but different name?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/70191/45266)

The question has an error in it (Cdim and Cm7b5 aren't actually the same chord!), but all the answers address the question with the error.

I tried to edit the question out multiple times, and even voted to close it, but I can't. I even got suspended for a full year for that.

So instead of trying to break the rules, I decided to post this comment instead:

> You mean C HALF-dim and Cm7b5, right?

That way, the OP can see it and decide what to do.

Is this the proper way to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use comments for that purpose, yes - they are for asking for clarification, suggesting different info etc.

Your suspension was for a set of behaviours that we do not welcome here.